# Pandas. What is the best way to insert additional rows in dataframe based on cell values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

| id | name | emails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a@e.com,b@e.com,c@e.com,d@e.com |
| 2 | f | f@gmail.com |

And I need iterate over `emails` if there are more than one, create additional rows in dataframe with additional emails, not corresponding to name, should be like this:

| id | name | emails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a@e.com |
| 2 | f | f@gmail.com |
| 3 | NaN | b@e.com |
| 4 | NaN | c@e.com |
| 5 | NaN | d@e.com |

What is the best way to do it apart of iterrows with append or concat? is it ok to modify iterated dataframe during iteration?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use df.emails.apply() however it will not be as fast as a vectorized way. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: I didnt know we can add new rows to a dataframe with apply(). Do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with splitted values by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) first, then compare values before `@` and if no match set missing value and last sorting like missing values are in end of DataFrame with assign `range` to `id` column:

```
df = df.assign(emails = df['emails'].str.split(',')).explode('emails')

mask = df['name'].eq(df['emails'].str.split('@').str[0])
df['name'] = np.where(mask, df['name'], np.nan)

df = df.sort_values('name', key=lambda x: x.isna(), ignore_index=True)
df['id'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
print (df)
   id name       emails
0   1    a      a@e.com
1   2    f  f@gmail.com
2   3  NaN      b@e.com
3   4  NaN      c@e.com
4   5  NaN      d@e.com
```

Comment: Thanks, cool Solution!  However in real i have much complicated method to check name vs email, which for each pare of name/emails returns the closest email from the list and it's positional number.

Comment: @Oleksii - need some latest pandas version, I hope working well in real data too.

Comment: @Oleksii - Then the best is create new question for this new problem.